# Netty-based safely network reconnection

Tags: scala, thread-safety, networking, netty

I am writing a `TCP` client app using netty

**NettyConnectionManager.scala:**

```
class NettyConnectionManager(val config : NettyConfig) extends ConnectionManager {
  @volatile private var connection: Option[Connected] = None

  def get() = {
    if(isConnected) {
      connection.get
    } else {
      synchronized {
        if(isConnected) {
          connection.get
        } else {
          val newConnection = new NettyConnection(config)
          newConnection.connect()
          connection = Some(newConnection)
          connection.get
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private def isConnected = {
    (for(c <- connection if c.isConnected) yield true).getOrElse(false)
  }

  def close() {
    synchronized {
      if(isConnected) {
        connection.foreach(_.close())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NettyConnection:**

```
class NettyConnection(val config: NettyConfig) extends Connection {

  @volatile
  private var channel = None: Option[Channel]

  def connect() = {
    val channelFuture = bootstrap().connect(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(config.hostname, config.port))
    channelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly
    channel = Some(channelFuture.getChannel)
  }

  def isConnected = channel.map(_.isOpen).getOrElse(false)
  ...
```

I am trying to do auto-reconnect in `NettyConnectionManager`.

Now I have three questions:

1. Is `channel.isOpen` method reflect the channel states immediately?
2. Is `NettyConnectionManager` thread safe? (`get` method never return a closed connection more than one time).
3. Is there a better way doing such reconnect job?

Answer (score 1):

1. A netty Channel can be open and not connected so your `NettyConnection.isConnected` is not correct. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5714980/448141).
2. and 3.

It's pointless to write such code in scala. What you need is just a scala lazy val. Try this:

```
class NettyConnectionManager(val config: NettyConfig) extends ConnectionManager {
  lazy val connection = {
    val newConnection = new NettyConnection(config)
    newConnection.connect()
    newConnection
  }

  def close = connection.close
  def connected = connection.isConnected
}
```

scala lazy vals already use double check locking to initial the val only once, you don't have to do all the primitive stuff yourself as in `NettyConnectionManager` or `NettyConnection`. Next time you think about using var of Option, use lazy val instead. See [SIP-20](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html) to know more about how scala community is trying to improving this strategy.

And, wrapping a Channel in two classes like `NettyConnection` and `NettyConnectionManager` is also bad design decision. You gain little and add much unnecessary complexity.

Comment: 1. I use this netty connection for `tcp`, so it must be connected.
2&3. I want to reconnect at runtime(possibly reconnect happens multi times) not `lazy connect` actually